# Windows App plugin not working for react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-windows

I'm trying to provide windows support for my react native app but somehow it's not able to generate windows folder.

the first error is...
**rnpm-plugin-windows@0.2.11 requires a peer of react-native@>=0.31.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.**

Above error is coming when I entered the command `npm install --save-dev rnpm-plugin-windows`

Some time windows plugin is installed properly but below error will coming 
**"Windows" command not found** when I entered `react-native windows`

Answer (score 0):

You First `React-native-cli` install

1. `npm install -g react-native-cli`
2. `npm install --save-dev rnpm-plugin-windows`
3. `react-native init yourproject`

**Usage**

```
react-native windows [name] [--namespace <namespace>] [--windowsVersion <version>]
```